# String Interpolation a json object with %

Tags: java, string, string-interpolation

I am trying to send a custom payload to a String in Java. In this case, a JSON Object.

Ordinarily, if I wanted to send a decimal to a string I might do something like this

```java
String myDecimal = "my decimal is %d";
System.out.println(String.format(myDecimal, 20)); // print "my decimal is 20)
```

However, instead of sending a decimal, or a string (%s), I would like to send a JSON object. Is this possible, if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot pass an object. so far, my best solution has been passing strings formatted to be like a JSON object, then parsing it into a JSON Object.

Example

```
class Main {
  private static String EXT_EVENT = "{" +
            "    \"version\": \"1.0\"," +
            "    \"method\": \"Event\"," +
            "    \"target\": \"ExamppleTarget\"," +
            "    \"name\": \"OnEventReceived\"," +
            "    \"payload\": { \"header\": %1$s," +
            "                   \"endpoint\": %2$s, " +
            "                   \"payload\": %3$s }" +
            "}";
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String example = String.format(EXT_EVENT,"test1", "test2", "test3");
    System.out.println(example);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With [Java 15 text blocks](https://www.baeldung.com/java-text-blocks), it can be simplified a little bit:

```java
private static String EXT_EVENT = """
    {
        "version": "1.0",
        "method":  "Event",
        "target":  "ExampleTarget",
        "name":    "OnEventReceived",
        "payload": {
            "header":   %1$s,
            "endpoint": %2$s,
            "payload":  %3$s
        }
    }
""";
String example = String.format(EXT_EVENT, "test1", "test2", "test3");
```

Or even with [Java template strings and string interpolation](https://openjdk.org/jeps/430) (to be introduced in Java **21** as a preview feature):

```java
private static String h = "test1";
private static String e = "test2";
private static String p = "test3";
private static String example = STR."""
    {
        "version": "1.0",
        "method":  "Event",
        "target":  "ExampleTarget",
        "name":    "OnEventReceived",
        "payload": {
            "header":   \{h},
            "endpoint": \{e},
            "payload":  \{p}
        }
    }
""";
```

Comment: Note that Java 15 also allows to write `String example = EXT_EVENT.formatted("test1", "test2", "test3");` And the current state of JEP-430 is that you’ll have to prefix the template string with `STR.` to use string interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java's String Templates feature.
It is described in [JEP 430](https://openjdk.org/jeps/430), and it appears in JDK 21 as a preview feature.  Here is an example use that outputs a **String**:

```java
String name = "Joan";
String info = STR."My name is \{name}";
assert info.equals("My name is Joan");   // true
```

Java's string templates are more versatile, and much safer, than features in other languagues such as C#'s string interpolation and Python's f-strings.  For example, here is a template processor that returns not strings but, rather, instances of **JSONObject**:

```java
var JSON = StringTemplate.Processor.of(
        (StringTemplate st) -> new JSONObject(st.interpolate())
    );

String name    = "Joan Smith";
String phone   = "555-123-4567";
String address = "1 Maple Drive, Anytown";
JSONObject doc = JSON."""
    {
        "name":    "\{name}",
        "phone":   "\{phone}",
        "address": "\{address}"
    };
    """;
```